# How common is it for a native speaker to use "i.e." in their conversation?

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

1. How common is "i.e." in everyday conversation? If so,
2. How do native speakers pronounce it? "id est" or something else?

Comment: By the way, only a small thing,  but look up the meaning of "native".  It doesn't mean the same as "a native speaker of English".

Comment: @JamesK Yes, it was a good point. You hit the nail on the head. But as this website is for learning English, my mean was a native speaker of English, and not, for instance, a native speaker of French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very common.  But it would always be pronounced  "eye ee" /ai i:/  The Latin phrase is not well known by English speakers.

It is more likely that a speaker would say "that is" instead of speaking "i.e."

Comment: I would call someone who said "i.e.", "e.g.", "w.e.f." etc a _very clumsy communicator_.

Comment: Although I have heard people triumphantly saying "QED!" after proving something.

Comment: Initialisms in spoken English are not that unusual,  particularly in informal contexts.  from omg to wtf.

Comment: I sometimes say omfg.